# Firebase [Swift Package Manager]: no such module FirebaseRemoteConfig

Tags: ios, firebase, swift-package-manager, xcode12.5

After I read the instructions listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/swift-package-manager#via-package-dot-swift) for how to add `Firebase` as a dependency to a Swift package, I couldn't get it to work, here's my `Package.swift` manifest:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "MyPackage",
            targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(name: "Firebase",
                 url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",
                 .upToNextMajor(from: "8.0.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "FirebaseRemoteConfig", package: "Firebase")]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

the package graph resolves without problems, but when I try to add my own code in `Sources/MyPackage.swift` starting with `import FirebaseRemoteConfig` the compiler complains with:
`No such model 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'`.

what's went wrong with my setup ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the solution, but unfortunately it's not documented on Firebase Docs, I have to add the `.platforms` array in the `Package.swift` manifest specifying a version that supports FirebaseRemoteConfig, for example:

```
platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ]
```